# Syntax for accessing tokens exposed from workflow event

Tags: orchardcms

I've created a custom workflow event that is working fine. I'm trying to expose some tokens from this event that I'll use in an email step later in the workflow but can't seem to get at them.

Here's how I'm triggering the workflow event:

```
_workflowManager.TriggerEvent("MyEvent", null,
    () => new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "MyToken", "My Token's Value" } 
    });
```

In my email activity later in the workflow I'd like to access the token. I've tried the following but they don't seem to work:

```
{MyToken}
{Workflow.State:MyToken}
```

I've stepped through the code in the debugger but can't seem to wrap my head around how to access these tokens.

Comment: Please show the code that's defining the token `MyToken`. You do have a token, right? ;)

Comment: I don't have one :) I was under the impression that I could put whatever I want into the dictionary and they would be exposed as tokens. For instance, in [this driver](https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Roles/Drivers/UserTaskDriver.cs) in the Roles module it adds a couple tokens but never defines them. I've also tried populating the Content token but it comes through empty.

Comment: Added a token provider and now it's working. Not sure why I got the idea that TriggerEvent would expose whatever I put in the dictionary. If you want to create and answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Not sure however what tokens you're referring to in the roles  module: I don't see anything in there that's not defined elsewhere.

Comment: It was the UserTask.Action token. Probably just missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define tokens for what you want to expose. I suppose it would be a useful feature to auto-translate strings into a text token, but that's not how it works currently.